# Are there any online earth science formula/equation libraries?

Tags: models, numerical-modelling, database

I'm looking for a formula library like [fxSolver](https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/) but specifically for Earth science formulas. I *could* rummage through scientific papers like a nerd racoon, but first I want to make sure there isn't a website that has collected the equations I want. All of my "knowledge" in this field comes from intuition and a small number of basic qualitative descriptions, hence why I want to be able to browse through them and cherry pick the ones I need to learn about.

Comment: Science is not memorising formulae. Once you work in the field, you will learn those you need automatically. Besides that, any general field like 'Earth science' would contain too many equations with specialized variants and approximations to memorize. That's what books and articles are for.